# How to group Sonar results by severity (MAJOR, MINOR,CRITICAL) in intellij community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, intellij-14

I would like to categorize `SonarQube` results by severity 'major'. I have installed `SonarQube` plugin in intellij community edition(version 14.1.4). When i try to run the sonar `Analyze -> Inspect` code, The inspection window shows all the issues by rule but does not categorize the issues by major, minor and critical. I would really appreciate if anyone has achieved this using IntelliJ IDEA Community edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this open github [request](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin/issues/95), it looks like it used to be there in v1, but was subsequently removed. For what it's worth you can do this to help (excerpt from the link):

- Expand All
- Click somewhere in the window and start typing Type **MAJOR**
- if you want to find all **MAJOR** issues

Comment: This works for a single maven project. It does not work for a project with parent pom. so for a multi module maven project, I had to add the sonar resource for every module and analyze it for every module in intellij

Comment: I am able to see the sonar issues but when i fix the issues locally and try to run the analysis again, the plugin still shows the same issue. Could you pls let me know if you have achieved this. i have configured sonar qube server in my IDE and added sonar qube resources. Is it because, the plugin always tries to fetch the sonar issues from the server. How can i analyze the sonar issues locally.? pls help

Answer (score 2):

I found that in Intellij 2018.3.4, it's more useful to do code analysis through the main menu: Analyze->Inspect Code, which does a good job of grouping them by rule. It's not the same as Sonar, but there's a lot of overlap. Hopefully the plugin eventually gets improved.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy and direct way to categorize severity with SonarLint plugin on intellij.

Below is what I found helpful.

So goto to File->Settings->Sonarlint-> General settings-> Rules

Enable/Disable Blocker, Critical, Major rules of your choice. Re-run analysis to see only the rules you want. 
Like-wise select all blockers if you need to see blocker issues only.