# How to group SonarLint for Eclipse 3.2.0 results by severity (MAJOR, MINOR, CRITICAL)?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

How can I group or sort the `SonarLint for Eclipse` analysis results by severity?

I have installed `SonarLint For Eclipse` plugin version 3.2.0 in `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers` version Neon.2 4.6.2.  I right-click on an Eclipse project and select `SonarLint->Analyze`.  Eclipse populates the `SonarLint Report` view with a "flat" list of all issues found.  Sadly, there appears to be no way to group or sort the items by severity major, minor and critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known missing feature of `SonarLint For Eclipse`.

If you'd like the feature, vote for this JIRA issue:
*Add filtering capabilities on the On-The-Fly and Report views based on issue classifications*
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-195
which has the description:

> We could offer:
>   filter / group by issue severity
>   filter / group by issue type
>   filter issue tag (no group by since tags are not limited to a fixed list of values)

Note that the SonarLint for IntellJ also lacks this feature according to this StackOverflow item:
[How to group Sonar results by severity (MAJOR, MINOR,CRITICAL) in intellij community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069088/how-to-group-sonar-results-by-severity-major-minor-critical-in-intellij-commu)